# timepicker.js - time-picker wrong position in some case

Tags: javascript, npm, time, timepicker

I am using timepicker.js library to pick a time. On input click, timepicker should be shown next to input field. It works like expected if the input is in main view of document. If the input is situated lower (we need to scroll to see it) and we click it, the timepicker is shown more higher, in the main view page.

Expected behaviour:
[image]

Behaviour for inputs after scrolling lower:
[image]

I'd like to have timepicker next to input field in second case also, like in first case.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="time1" placeholder="Time" />
    <div style="height: 70rem;"></div>
    <input type="text" id="time2" placeholder="Time" value="18:00" />
    <div style="height: 70rem;"></div>
  </body>
  <link
    href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
  />
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var time1 = document.getElementById("time1");
var time2 = document.getElementById("time2");
var timepicker = new TimePicker(["time1", "time2"], {
  lang: "en"
});

timepicker.on("change", function(evt) {
  var value = (evt.hour || "00") + ":" + (evt.minute || "00");
  evt.element.value = value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the style / css is setting position to absolute as opposed to relevant to the textbox control or area. I would load F12 dev tools and look into the CSS around the date picker to see if any classes or styles are being overwritten, namely around position values, or top / bottom etc...